# Hibernate, find substring of an objects field variable

Tags: hibernate

Is it possible to make a hibernate search query to find substrings of a class field varibles. For example:

```
public class User {

private String username = "asoftdrink";

}
```

and make a hibernate query to find all objects of class User which cointains the substring "soft" in their variable username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Restrictions.like()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#like(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.criterion.MatchMode))

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("username", "soft", MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

This is equivalent to

```
where username like '%soft%'
```

in SQL. Keep in mind, though, this won't be very efficient since the database can't use an index to execute the query.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this out. Are there some more efficient ways?